# GLSL fast screen pattern

Tags: algorithm, optimization, glsl, modulo

I work in 2D on the full screen by texturing a quad.

I divide each line into multiple 5-pixel spaces.
Only one pixel on the 5 is white, the others are black.
This pattern is repeated all along the line, at each line.

So if 1 is white, and 0 is black:

1st pass = 10000 10000 10000 etc. on entire line, and each lines.

2nd pass = 01000 01000 01000 etc.

3rd pass = 00100 00100 00100 etc.

4th pass = 00010 00010 00010 etc.

5th pass = 00001 00001 00001 etc.

6th pass = 10000|10000|10000 (like the 1st pass)
etc.

step_x is the number of the white pixel (between 1 and 5), it changes with each pass.

In others words, if step_x == 2, the white pixels are at columns 2, 7, 12, 17 etc.

I can't use the modulo operation without using multiple conditions that slow down the execution.

I need efficiency on this part because I use it a lot in my code.

That's why I'm asking for help: how to get the same result more effectively?

Maybe something with fract() or step() functions, that I tried without success (I think I don't really understand these two functions.)

Here is my code, which works:

shader code:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;
uniform int step_x;

#define Xmax 5

vec4 white_if_posX_is_Multiple() {
int mod_x = int(mod(gl_FragCoord.x, Xmax));
if (step_x == Xmax && mod_x < 1.0) return vec4(1.0f);
if (mod_x == step_x;) return vec4(1.0f);
return vec4(0.0f);
}

void main()
{
    FragColor = white_if_posX_is_Multiple();
}
```

C++ OpenGL code:

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    shader.use();
    shader.setInt("step_x", x);
    renderQuad();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use something like :

```
return vec4(1.0f - step(0.5f,mod(gl_FragCoord.x-step_x+1, Xmax)));
```

Be careful, in some implementations you should not give negative values to `mod`. In that case, just add `+Xmax` at the end of the `mod` first parameter.

Comment: I have no way to test it right now, so please let me know if this works !

Comment: Thank you for your help.I needed to cast the mod into an int, then it work. Can you please explain the "step(0.5f" ?

Comment: @GUNNM `step(0.5,x)` gives 0 if x is below 0.5, and 1 if x is above 0.5 - thus the name "step".